# Compression makes slow response time

Tags: performance, iis-6, compression

I have reacently activated gzip compression on an `IIS6` webserver. I use both static and dynamic compression (static level 10 and dyamic level 1). This was a measure to increase server response time performance. However it seems like the page loads slower after the compression was activated. All my measurements in firebug indicate this.

Has anyone else had this problem? What can be the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing more work on the server and the client so it is normal that response times increase. On low bandwidth connections you might make it good with reduced transfer times.

If you are on a high bandwidth connection then the compression will have not have a significant impact on the transfer delay as it is already short uncompressed. However you will pay 100% of the CPU penalty.

Now zipping large responses takes quite some CPU power, if the server CPU's are already loaded the response times might even get worse.

My advice : check the server CPU and if it is non-negligeable then either turn off zipping or buy a bigger box. If you have a large population on mobile or in remote locations with poor internet connectivity then zipping might be useful, otherwise it will make little difference.

You might also look in using a reverse proxy to reduce the load of the server.

Comment: Indeed I forgot the poor enterprise intranet users on very expensive overloaded T1/E1 lines. In those cases a reverse proxy on the remote locations might do wonders (as well as a bigger box ;-).

Answer (score 1):

How much bandwidth do you have between your browser and your server?
compressing and decompressing the stream is more work, and so on a fast network, it may actually be slower -- is this an intranet application?  You will see the most gain for compression if you have tight bandwidth requirements (either lots of traffic, or a lower bandwidth connection.

How much compression helps will also depend upon what kind of content your site is delivering.

The best thing to do is to test and measure under the same conditions that your site will be under when it is in production.

Answer (score 1):

Static compression works quite well because a copy of the gzipped file is placed in a temporary folder, however dynamically compressed responses have to be re-gzipped every time and unless the bandwidth is a big problem I don't think it is worth it.